# Does delayed_job still work with mongo_mapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, mongomapper

There are some existing questions for previous versions but from searching SO and googling I am unable to work out if mongo_mapper and delayed_job still work together and if so how to make it happen. I believe the two at least *used* to work together.

I'd like to use:

- Rails 3.0.10
- MongoMapper 0.9.2
- DelayedJob 2.1.4

However I believe I also need

- delayed_job_mongo_mapper

which at the version I have, 1.0, requires MongoMapper 0.8.6.

So I am using MongoMapper 0.8.6 instead.

However, when running:

```
rails runner 'Delayed::Backend::MongoMapper::Job.create_indexes'
```

as specified in the delayed_job_mongo_mapper readme I get the following exception:

```
uninitialized constant MongoMapper::Plugins::Caching::ClassMethods (NameError)
```

Does anyone have recent versions of MongoMapper and DelayedJob working together and can you please tell me how you did it? Thanks.

EDIT:

I've also tried it with the current version of mongo_mapper and no delayed_job_mongo_mapper, but I get `uninitialized constant Delayed::Job` whenever I try to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I carried on googling and finally found [this](https://github.com/andrewtimberlake/delayed_job_mongo_mapper/issues/1) description of someone having the same problem, who fixed it by using a more recent version of MongoMapper and fork of the delayed_job_mongo_mapper project [here](https://github.com/earbits/delayed_job_mongo_mapper).

It turned out that there was a problem with this fork too as since it was last tested MongoDB have changed the `findAndModify` command to return nil rather than throw an error if no document is found, which makes delayed_job_mongo_mapper break when there are no more jobs left.

So I forked the project myself [here](https://github.com/rsslldnphy/delayed_job_mongo_mapper) to fix that issue, and I now have everything working (so far).